# Get key name from Python KeyError exception

Tags: python, exception

I would like to get the key name from the Python `KeyError` exception:

For example:

```
myDict = {'key1':'value1'}
try:
    x1 = myDict['key1']
    x2 = myDict['key2'] 
except KeyError as e:
    # here i want to use the name of the key that was missing which is 'key2' in this example
    print error_msg[missing_key]
```

i have already tried this

```
print e
print e.args
print e.message
```

my code is inside django view !

if i use ipython for example and try e.arg or e.message it works fine. 
but then i try it while inside a django view i get this results:

```
"Key 'key2' not found in <QueryDict: {u'key1': [u'value']}>" 
("Key 'key2' not found in <QueryDict: {u'key1': [u'value']}>",) 
Key 'key2' not found in <QueryDict: {u'key1': [u'value']}>
```

while i just want the 'key2'

Comment: Is that just for logging, or are you actually going to do something with the key?

Comment: you can see that if i use args[0] i get the first element from the tuple which is the same as i get when i print e.message

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Running your block of code in my Python interpreter does not print out that long message when I print the exception, only the key name (which is what all the answers are saying). Clearly yours is different!

Comment: i use python 2.7 i think it is different because my code is inside a django view. if i use ipython i get the same result as all of you

Comment: Do you have more than one version of Python on your system?  If so, is iPython running the same version as Django?  (Just a thought ...)

Comment: The errors you show indicate that this is a QueryDict, a Django construction, not a regular Python dictionary.  Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Django so do not know whether a KeyError from a QueryDict will behave the same as a Python dict; this is something you may want to investigate.

Answer (score -15, accepted):

As your dictionary is actually a `QueryDict`, and therefore returns a different error message, you will need to parse the exception message to return the first word in single quotes:

```
import re
#...
except KeyError as e:
    m = re.search("'([^']*)'", e.message)
    key = m.group(1)
```

Comment: i thought maybe there is a way without a workaround, but if i cant find one i will use this, thanks !

Comment: This is unnecessary complex, slow, memory+CPU ineffective and future error prone. AVOID it!

Answer (score 108):

You can use `e.args`:

```
[53]: try:
    x2 = myDict['key2']
except KeyError as e:    
    print e.args[0]
   ....:     
key2
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html):

> The except clause may specify a variable after the exception name (or
>   tuple). The variable is bound to an exception instance with the
>   arguments stored in `instance.args`

Answer (score 3):

```
myDict = {'key1':'value1'}
try:
    x1 = myDict['key1']
    x2 = myDict['key2'] 
except KeyError as e:
    # here i want to use the name of the key that was missing which is 'key2' in this example
    print "missing key in mydict:", e.message
```

Comment: This may have been the case in Python 2.x, but does not work in Python 3 as "message" has been deprecated and removed: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0352/#transition-plan

Answer (score 1):

For KeyErrors, the 2nd element (index 1) of [sys.exc_info()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) holds the key:

```
import sys
try:
    x1 = myDict['key1']
    x2 = myDict['key2'] 
except KeyError:
    print 'KeyError, offending key:', sys.exc_info()[1]
```

Output:

> KeyError, offending key: 'key2'

Comment: i get the same result as if i use print e

Comment: The question was edited after I provided this answer.  I'm not currently knowledgeable about Django, so don't know if this will work or not within that context, although I think it should.

Comment: @yossi:  See my comment to the question about QueryDict.

Answer (score -3):

Simply, the response of the KeyError is the key itself in case you want to make use of it you just need to call the error as it is.

```python
myDict = {'key1':'value1'}

try:
    x1 = myDict['key1']
    x2 = myDict['key2'] 
except KeyError as missing_key:
    # Used as missing_key for readability purposes only
    print(f"Trying to access a <dict> with a missing key {missing_key}")
```

P.S. This was tested on Python version `3.8.12`

Comment: Even though this will work, it is misleading as missing_key is not a string object but an error object. It works because when an error object is formatted into a string it will trigger the __str__ function.