# How to I get the missing key from a KeyError in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, exception

I am writing a helper function were I need to know what key is missing when a KeyError is raised.

Consider this:

```
def foo(x:dict):
  
   try:
      y = x['A']
   except KeyError as ke:
      return ke

foo(dict())
```

As intended, the code above raises a KeyError. More specifically, the repr is `KeyError('A')`.

I want to access that "A" that is missing, but it does not seem to be an attribute of the `KeyError` object.

Any ideas?

Ps. The reason I'm doing this is because I want to write a function of the form

```
def check_calculation_dependency_on_data(calculation:callable, data:pd.DataFrame)->list[str]:
   '''Returns the mandatory columns data needs to contain for the calculation to work'''
```

I have a version of the above where data starts with all columns and progressively removes them one at a time (inside a try-except block) to list the columns that raise a KeyError if missing. However, the code would be much more efficient if it starts with an empty dataframe and I add the missing columns one by one until no KeyError is raised.

Comment: You already know you want to access `'A'`, why would you want to extract something you already know. e.g. if you have a list of column names - iterate over it, and get the keys that raise error. There may be other ways too, e.g. use .`get()` and find the keys that return `None`

Comment: Either way this solution is messy and brittle (can stop working due to small changes in other code). Where are the callables coming from, such that you don't know what columns they access?

Comment: You can do one of these things
`print(foo(dict()))` or `print(type(ke).__name__, ke)`

Comment: You can compare and find the intercept or difference of set(all keys) and set(dict.keys()) or set(dataframe.columns)

Comment: Thanks all. In the end `ke.args[0]` worked for me as per the accepted answer.
Regarding `why` I'm doing this - it's because I have a dataframe with 500+ columns, and dozens of functions that make calculations from that dataframe. Each of these leverage helpers that themselves make calculations from the dataframe. It's non-trivial to keep track of the dependencies across the full codebase.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alredy answered here [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745514/get-key-name-from-python-keyerror-exception)

```
map1 = {}
try:
    x = map1['key2']
except KeyError as e:    
    print(e.args[0])
```